# How to organize the Rails structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a very big question about Rails. Suppose that we need to create a web site about blogs, we allow user registration and the user has their own management interface which make it possible for them to add, delete, edit, and select the article and comment. The operation on the `article` and `comment` might be used in other positions in the future.

So we have a `article` model and a `comment` model.

Now we create a users controller:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController    
  def articleList   
  end

  def articleSave   
  end

  def articleUpdate 
  end

  def articleDestroy    
  end

  def articleEdit   
  end

  def articleAdd    
  end

  def commentList   
  end

  def commentDestroy    
  end

  def commentEdit   
  end
end
```

But it din't look good, and when the user management control has many features, this user controller will be very big. Should I create an `article` controller and `comment` controller to process the request? Just separated into the article controller is like this:

```
class ArticleController < ApplicationController 
  def list      
  end

  def save  
  end

  def update    
  end

  def destroy   
  end

  def edit
  end

  def add   
  end
end
```

Comment controller is as follows:

```
class CommentController < ApplicationController      
  def list  
  end

  def destroy
  end

  def edit  
  end

  def update
  end
end
```

I don't know how to organize the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have separate controllers for each of the `Users` `Articles` and `Comments`, but nest them with `Comments` inside `Articles`, and `Articles` inside `Users`. This seems to fit the relationship between the concepts as you've described them

See 
http://www.sentia.com.au/blog/when-to-use-nested-controllers-in-your-rails-apps
and
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources
for more on nesting controllers.